# Is someone deliberating downvoting my posts?

Tags: support, down-votes

Some days ago I had an argument with a user about tension being a force on a post, since then I am constantly receiving at least one downvote on all my posts, maybe it is not related but I believe that the person is deliberately down voting all my quetions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

There are two features of the engine designed to combat this kind of thing:

- There is a script which detects and reverses short-term voting sprees over some threshold (but it only runs once a day, so you do have to be patient with it).
- The moderators have a tool that will show such a pattern in the long run. As of this post you do not appear in the summary nor do the details look actionable.

Comment: Only if I were a moderator :( downvotes for me :(